# DataGridView CellFormatting performance issue

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

How to fix `CellFormatting` "slow scrolling" performance issue?

Using this code to copy decrypted values from encrypted column to another column:

```
private void grid_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex < 0 || e.RowIndex < 0)
        return;

    var columnB = grid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex];
    if (columnB.Name != "B")
        return;

    var value = grid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["A"].Value;
    if (value == null || value == DBNull.Value)
        return;

    e.Value = Decrypt(value.ToString());
}
```

Comment: You can use a DoubleBuffered DGV if the issue is in fact the CellPainting. If the Decryption is, well you could put the decrypted value in the Cell.Tag, but this may not be what you want securitywise..

Comment: @TaW Its doublebuffered dgv.

Comment: Just to be sure: You use a DoubleBuffered DataGridView __subclass__? (Many newbies believe they can turn on DoubleBuffering for all controls via the Form's DoubleBuffered  property..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the performance issue is because of `Decrypt` method, you should avoid using it in `CellFormatting` as mentioned in remarks part of the event's documentations:

> The [`CellFormatting`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1) event occurs every time each cell is painted, so
>   you should avoid lengthy processing when handling this event.

**what solution can I use to provide value for the second column based on first column?**

You can use either of these options:

1. Add second column to `DataGridView` and provide the value in a for loop.
2. Add second column to your data source (for example your `DataTable`) and provide the value in a for loop.

**Example**

In the below example, it doesn't make any difference if you load data from database. But to provide a minimal complete verifiable example, I created `DataTable` myself. In both examples `LoadData` method, loads a `DataTable`:

```
private DataTable LoadData()
{
    var dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("ExistingColumn");
    dt.Rows.Add("x");
    dt.Rows.Add("y");
    dt.Rows.Add("z");
    return dt;
}
```

*Example 1 - Add Column To DataGridView*

```
var dt = LoadData();
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
//Add new column to DataGridView
var newColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
newColumn.HeaderText = "NewColumn";
newColumn.Name = "NewColumn";
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(newColumn);
//Copy Values
foreach (DataGridViewRow r in this.dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    if(!r.IsNewRow)
        r.Cells["NewColumn"].Value = Decrypt(r.Cells["ExistingColumn"].Value.ToString());
}
```

*Example 2 - Add Column to DataTable*

```
var dt = LoadData();
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
//Add new column to DataTable
dt.Columns.Add("NewColumn");
//Copy Values
foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
    r["NewColumn"] = Decrypt(r.Field<string>("ExistingColumn");
```

Comment: In examples, I didn't perform null/dbnull checking on value of "ExistingColumn". You may need to check if there is null/dbull values in the column.

Comment: Did you perform test in a clean environment like I did? Let me know if you have any question about the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Dont use **`CellFormating`** method at all.

I found very well working solution finally.

Here is my code.

```
dgvTrucksMaster.SuspendLayout();
dgvTrucksMaster.DataSource = calendar.FailureCalendarDetails.OrderBy(x => x.MachineFullName).ToList();

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvTrucksMaster.Rows)
{
    if (Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells["Decade1Hours"].Value) > 0)
    {
        row.Cells["Decade1Hours"].Style.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
    }

    if (Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells["Decade1Hours"].Value) < 0)
    {
        // row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightSalmon;
        row.Cells["Decade1Hours"].Style.BackColor = Color.LightSalmon;
    }

    if (Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells["Decade2Hours"].Value) > 0)
    {
        row.Cells["Decade2Hours"].Style.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
    }

    if (Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells["Decade2Hours"].Value) < 0)
    {
        // row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightSalmon;
        row.Cells["Decade2Hours"].Style.BackColor = Color.LightSalmon;
    }

    if (Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells["Decade3Hours"].Value) > 0)
    {
        row.Cells["Decade3Hours"].Style.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
    }

    if (Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells["Decade3Hours"].Value) < 0)
    {
        // row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightSalmon;
        row.Cells["Decade3Hours"].Style.BackColor = Color.LightSalmon;
    }

    if (Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells["DecadeMonthHours"].Value) > 0)
    {
        row.Cells["DecadeMonthHours"].Style.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
    }

    if (Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells["DecadeMonthHours"].Value) < 0)
    {
        // row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightSalmon;
        row.Cells["DecadeMonthHours"].Style.BackColor = Color.LightSalmon;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 61; i++)
    {
        if (Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[string.Format("D{0}", i + 1)].Value) < 0)
        {
            row.Cells[string.Format("D{0}", i + 1)].Style.BackColor = Color.LightSalmon;
        }


        if (Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[string.Format("D{0}", i + 1)].Value) > 0)
        {
            row.Cells[string.Format("D{0}", i + 1)].Style.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
        }
    }
}

dgvTrucksMaster.ResumeLayout();
```

As you see from the code the key is to change `CellFormating` after you apply `Data Source` and before `ResumeLayout` method.

Just try it and you will satisfy with result.

Oh! And make sure you do it within **`BeginInvoke((Action)(() => {  // Some code });`**  code. So please get and prepare `Data Source` ***asynchronously***.